filter_input always returns null
I must be doing something fundamentally wrong here, but I cannot see what it is. In the process of discovering what exactly filter_input does, I wrote this test to show the gozintas and gozoutas.
for($i = 0; $i <= 255; ++$i) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        $c1 = "What@The@Heck";
    } else {
        $c1 = chr($i);
    }
    
    $_GET['c1'] = $c1;
    print "GET="; var_dump($_GET); print "<br>";
    $c2 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'c1');
    $c3 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'c1', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $c4 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'c1', FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
    $c5 = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'c1', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY);
    
    print "i=$i c1=$c1 c2=$c2 c3=$c3 c4=$c4 c5=$c5<br>";
    print "c5=";var_dump($c5); print "<br>";
}

All the output looks like this:
...
GET=array(1) { ["c1"]=> string(1) ">" }
i=62 c1=> c2= c3= c4= c5=
c5=NULL
GET=array(1) { ["c1"]=> string(1) "?" }
i=63 c1=? c2= c3= c4= c5=
c5=NULL
GET=array(1) { ["c1"]=> string(1) "@" }
i=64 c1=@ c2= c3= c4= c5=
c5=NULL
GET=array(1) { ["c1"]=> string(1) "A" }
i=65 c1=A c2= c3= c4= c5=
c5=NULL
GET=array(1) { ["c1"]=> string(1) "B" }
i=66 c1=B c2= c3= c4= c5=
c5=NULL
GET=array(1) { ["c1"]=> string(1) "C" }
i=67 c1=C c2= c3= c4= c5=
c5=NULL
...

It's really confounding because I know filter_input is used elsewhere in our code in the same way without problems. I'm running PHP 8.3.11. Have mercy on a burned-out programmer.

You manually set $_GET['c1'] in your test script within a loop and then trying to get it with filter_input. Since filter_input fetches the data from the original HTTP request,  it doesn't recognize these internal assignments.
Using filter_var instead of filter_input
for ($i = 0; $i <= 255; ++$i) {
    if ($i == 0) {
        $c1 = "What@The@Heck";
    } else {
        $c1 = chr($i);
    }

    $_GET['c1'] = $c1;
    echo "GET="; var_dump($_GET); echo "<br>";

    // Using filter_var instead of filter_input
    $c2 = filter_var($_GET['c1'], FILTER_DEFAULT);
    $c3 = filter_var($_GET['c1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $c4 = filter_var($_GET['c1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
    $c5 = filter_var($_GET['c1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS); # changed

    echo "i=$i c1=$c1 c2=$c2 c3=$c3 c4=$c4 c5=$c5<br>";
    echo "c5="; var_dump($c5); echo "<br>";
}

FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING is deprecated in PHP 8.1.0. Use FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS

Read More

When is filter_input() used versus filter_var()?
Difference between filter_var and filter_input on input data validation
PHP's new input_filter does not read $_GET or $_POST arrays

